# How can you use jQuery mobile's Column-Toggle without applying the mobile style to your whole page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to use the jQuery Mobile [Column-Toggle](http://api.jquerymobile.com/table-columntoggle/) widget in a web application that will be almost exclusively used by non-mobile users, so I really just want the Column picker functionality, without any of the other jQuery Mobile features.  However, if I load the jQuery Mobile js and css, my entire site picks up the mobile style, which conflicts horribly with my existing stlying.

I've tried several mobileinit options that supposedly should suppress the mobile styling (I've tried various combinations of these settings - I'm just combining them all here for brevity):

```
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
        $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;
        $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true;
        $.mobile.page.prototype.options.keepNative = "select, input, a";
    });
```

The other option I've seen is to add data-role="none" to all of the elements you don't want to style, but that has two problems:

1. It doesn't work for me (I'm still investigating why, and will update my question soon).
2. It seems like bad practice to junk up your html with a ton of suppression tags, which also increase the page size.

I've tried using the download builder to create a customer jQuery Mobile package with only the Column-Toggle (and dependency) module, but that custom package doesn't seem to work at all.

So I have two questions really:

1. Is there an alternative column picker for HTML tables that I can use instead of the jQuery Mobile version.  I feel like I have done extensive web research, but have found nothing else.
2. What methods exist to prevent jQuery Mobile from applying it's style to your whole page?  There are a few other SO questions about this, and I'm afraid that there just isn't any currently working method to do so.

**Update**:  I've actually changed to using the new [column selection widget](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-column-selector.html) in the tablesorter plugin, and scrapped jQuery Mobile.

Comment: 1) you can create a custom jQM and choose widgets you want to use. You really dont need to load jQM JS and CSS for one widget. http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/ 2) if you're using jQM 1.4 `$.mobile.keepNative = "selectors";` 3) if you choose to use a custom build, you'll need to initialize _table_ widget manually `$(".selector").table-columntoggle();`.

Comment: Oooh.  I didn't know you had to initialize the widget manually with the custom build. That may be what I was missing.  I'll try that and report back.

Comment: This is in case you didn't check _Init_, 4th option in _Core_.

Comment: Excuse my jQuery naivete - but table-columntoggle doesn't appear to be defined.  I did find it in the documentation, but I'm not able to reference it in my js (which is run *after* I source the jQuery mobile customer JS).  I saw that the columntoggle code was refactored a bit in 1.4.0, but I saw the same thing in 1.3.2.

Comment: have you tried calling `.table()`?